# Hide default validation error message

Tags: error

My code is something similar to the one written below where I have an email field which shows validation error in both `apex:pagemessages` and the actual error below the field when email format is not correct.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My question is is there a way to hide the error message that comes below the field and display only the error in pagemessages.

- I tried with CSS by adding display:none property and got the result.

But would like to know if there is much better idea in completing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer and posting here just in case if any one has the same situation..

add attribute `required=false` inside `<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}"/>`

so it should be :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}" required = "false"/>
```